# How to convert command output to an array line by line in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm trying to convert the output of a command like `echo -e "a b\nc\nd e"` to an array.

```
X=( $(echo -e "a b\nc\nd e") )
```

Splits the input for every new line and whitespace character:

```
$ echo ${#X[@]}
> 5

for i in ${X[@]} ; do echo $i ; done
a
b
c
d
e
```

The result should be:

```
for i in ${X[@]} ; do echo $i ; done
a b
c
d e
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an array in bash from a command variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750848/how-do-i-create-an-array-in-bash-from-a-command-variable)

Comment: Someone might be able to find a better duplicate; that's just the most recent one. This question has probably been asked dozens of times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to change your *Internal Field Separator* variable (`IFS`) to a newline first.

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; arr=( $(echo -e "a b\nc\nd e") ); for i in ${arr[@]} ; do echo $i ; done
a b
c
d e
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I'm wondering why you use `echo -e` and not just `echo`. Any reason?

Comment: the `-e` flag tells echo to interpret backslash escape characters such as `\n` to output a newline vs a literal `\n`

Answer (score 4):

```
readarray -t ARRAY < <(COMMAND)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `IFS` to `newline`. By default, it is `space`.

```
[jaypal:~] while IFS=$'\n' read -a arry; do 
echo ${arry[0]}; 
done < <(echo -e "a b\nc\nd e")
a b
c
d e
```

Comment: No, by default it is `$' \t\n'`, spaces tabs and newlines.